# Elastic Search: Numeric range and < and > search in string field

Tags: elasticsearch

I have indexed multiple file contents containing numbers and dates in it as a separate entity (documents) in to elastic search. Now I would like make a search to get all the documents where numbers in text is < 235. Also fetch all documents where date in the text is > that 20/15/2015. Basically I am looking to perform numeric and date search in string field. Should we use any specific analyzers?

I remember this is possible in Apache Lucene. Since elastic search is written over the Lucene, there should be way too. But not sure the query and index -mapping pattern. Any suggetions?

UPDATE:

Dear Rob

Here are the following indexes I made.

```
POST /megacorp/employee113/2
{
    "first_name" :  "Douglas",
    "last_name" :   "Fir",
    "age" :         35,
    "about":        "I like to 26 build cabinets",
    "interests":  [ "forestry" ]
}
POST /megacorp/employee113/3
{
    "first_name" :  "Douglas",
    "last_name" :   "Fir",
    "age" :         35,
    "about":        "I like to 78 build cabinets",
    "interests":  [ "forestry" ]
}
POST /megacorp/employee114/7
{
    "first_name" :  "Douglas",
    "last_name" :   "Fir",
    "age" :         35,
    "about":        "I like to 158 build cabinets",
    "interests":  [ "forestry" ]
}
```

And I am search using your query. I get incorrect values.
I tried with query [10 TO 50], I get the 3rd one as "I like to 158 build cabinets" result.

Comment: May you post index mapping and the query which you tried?

Comment: 'POST /megacorp/employee114/7
{
    "first_name" :  "Douglas",
    "last_name" :   "Fir",
    "age" :         35,
    "about":        "I like to 158 build cabinets",
    "interests":  [ "forestry" ]
}

POST /megacorp/_search
{
   "query": {
      "range": {
         "about":{
             "gt" : 10,
             "lt": 30
             }
      }
   }  
}
' Also I tried with term 'POST /megacorp/_search
{
   "query": {
    "constant_score" : {
        "filter" : {
            "term" : { "about" : ["26" , "78"]}
        }
    }
   }  
}
'

Comment: Now I see query string doesn't work well in this case. I was testing it with wrong data set. Sorry for introduced confusion.